# REST APIs to manage my twilio account users?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I created a Twilio account. I have two users in my Twilio account.

1. Owner
2. Developer

I want Twilio REST API Something like `GET /users` which should return me above two users list

Seems OAuth is not supported by Twilio

I created `master` API Key for my account. ( This is not like OAuth it is valid only for my account, No cross-account call will be possible with this )

Are there any User management APIs provided by Twilio? ( I am not asking about subaccounts ) OR Any alternative OAuth like authentication for APIs?

***Update***

Based on a comment by @philnash I am adding few more points,

So if I create a Twilio account for my organization there I create few users for my organization, e.g.

```
1] Owner ( By default ) -> User1
2] Developer -> User2
3] Billing billing manager -> User3
4] Support -> User4
```

For the above users, I may need users API which may return my organization users list ( Provided I may need enabled REST API access & may have `access_token` ),

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "User1",
      "email": "user1@myorg.com",
      "role": "owner"
    },
    {
      "name": "User2",
      "email": "user2@myorg.com",
      "role": "developer"
    },
    {
      "name": "User1",
      "email": "user1@myorg.com",
      "role": "billing_manager"
    },
    {
      "name": "User1",
      "email": "user1@myorg.com",
      "role": "support"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looking for User management APIs for Twilio Main Account ( Close to Twilio connect but limitation there is it is for sub-accounts ).

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here. There isn't a users endpoint for an account, but what are you actually trying to achieve? Is [Twilio Connect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/connect) the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: @philnash thanks for the reply, I have updated the question hope that makes sense, Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is not a user management API for the Twilio API. Users are really the access credentials for a person to log in to the Twilio console. Users then have access to accounts and the account credentials (account SID and auth token) and API keys created for the account.

I am still unsure what you hope to do with the list of users that have access to your account. There is no Users API though.